# Drupal 7 Security Issues

Tags: drupal-7, security

1] I have My Account Page which is accessible after login.
Now i have looged in access 'My Account' Page & Logged Out.

Now when i clicked on browser back button i'm able to access 'My Account' page. Which is not true. When i refresh that page then it redirects to home page or u don't have access to this page. But on back browser button it don't work.

2] When user is logged in Take cookies Information using "Web Developer Tool" and save it in notepad.Delete all cookies infromation and closed the browser.Now open the browser and manually add the earliarly stored  Cookies details now access url user is already logged in using that cookies information. This should not happen.

Comment: you asked the same question on the Drupal site and deleted it later!!! any specific reason

Answer (score 1):

1. It's in the browser cache - not sure what Drupal could do about that.
2. That's how session cookies work. Again, I'm not sure what Drupal can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Its the browser that caches the page. If you hit back button, then the page is loaded from browser cache, rather than hitting the server again.
As this page is not loaded from the server, hence you see the last state of that page.

I am sure drupal or any other script cannot do about it.